# Intermittently slow Mysql table - why?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, intermittent

We recently had an issue I'd never seen before, where, for about 3 hours, one of our Mysql tables got extremely slow.  This table holds forum posts, and currently has about one million rows in it.  The query that became slow was a very common one in our application:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE (`posts`.forum_id = 1)  ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC LIMIT 1;
```

We have an index on the posts table on (forum_id, created_at) which normally allows this query and sort to happen in memory.  But, during these three hours, notsomuch.  What is normally an instantaneous query ranged from taking 2 seconds-45 seconds during this time period.  Then it went back to normal.

I've pored through our slow query log and nothing else looks out of the ordinary.  I've looked at New Relic (this is a Rails app) and all other actions ran essentially the same speed as normal.  We didn't have an unusual number of message posts today.  I can't find anything else weird in our logs.  And the database wasn't swapping, when it still had gigs of memory available to use.

I'm wondering if Mysql could change its mind back and forth about which indexes to use for a given query, and for whatever reason, it started deciding to do a full table scan on this query for a few hours today?  But if that were true, why would it have stopped doing the full table scans?

Has anyone else encountered an intermittently slow query that defied reason?  Or do you have any creative ideas about how one might go about debugging a problem like this?

Answer (score 2):

I'd try the [MySQL `EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) statement...

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE (`posts`.forum_id = 1)  ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC LIMIT 1;
```

It may be worth checking the MySQL response time in your Rails code, and if it exceeds a threshold then run the `EXPLAIN` and log the details somewhere.

[Table locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html) also springs to mind - is the posts table updated by a cronjob or hefty query while SELECTs are going on?

Hope that helps a bit!

Answer (score 2):

On a site I work on, we recently switched to InnoDB from MyISAM, and [we found that some simple select queries which had both WHERE and ORDER BY clauses were using the index for the ORDER BY clause](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/02/16/using-index-for-order-by-vs-restricting-number-of-rows/), resulting in a table scan to find the few desired rows (but, heck, they didn't need to be sorted when it finally found them all!)

As noted in the linked article, if you have a small LIMIT value, your ORDER BY clause is the first member of the primary key (so the data on file is ordered by it), and there are many results that match your WHERE clause, using that ORDER BY index isn't a bad idea for MySQL.  However, I presume created_at is not the first member of your primary key, so it's not a particularly smart idea in this case.

I don't know why MySQL would switch indexes if you haven't changed anything, but I'd suggest you try running ANALYZE TABLE on the relevant table.  You might also change the query to remove the LIMIT and ORDER BY clauses and sort at the application level, provided the result set is small enough; or you could add [a USE INDEX hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/6.0/en/index-hints.html) so it never guesses wrong.

You could also [change the wait_timeout value to something smaller](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) so that these queries that use a bad index simply never complete (but don't lag all of the legitimate queries too).  You will still be able to run long queries interactively, even with a small wait_timeout, since there is a separate configuration parameter for that.